# What happens if two simultaneous set to redis?

Tags: redis

For example, assuming the network is slow

00:00:00

client 1: set key1  a-very-big-value-around-400MB

client 2: set key1 short-value (Does this get blocked as client 1 is setting key1?)

If not block:

00:00:01

client 1: still writing to key1

client 2: successfully returned

00:00:02

client 1: still writing to key1

client 2: get key1 (return short-value?)

00:01:00

client 1: finished writing

client 2: get key1 (return short-value or a-very-big-value-around-400MB or something corrupted
 ?)

If a-very-big-value-around-400MB is returned, does this mean that redis first writes the value to some temp key then rename the key to key1??

Comment: If you issue two simultaneous SET, one of them will be processed first by the server, then the other. The result of a simultaneous GET will be the old value or either of the two new values. Afterwards, you will GET one of the two new values. There will be no corruption. If you need this to be deterministic, you need to coordinate the two SET operations somehow.

Comment: So if there are 100 simultaneous `set key1 a-very-big-value-around-400MB`, the temp memory used will be 100* 400MB?